# How to get the name of bindingsource which is currently binding to a control

Tags: vb.net, bindingsource

I have a textbox and I add bindingsource into it as a databinding, and then I want to get the name of the bindingsource, which is in the example bellow the bindingsource name is "bindingSource1". How to achive this? Because I have many bindingsource and sometime I changed the databinding of the textbox so that I need to check the name of bindingsource that currently bind to it. Thanks.

textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "Address", True)

Comment: There is no name, In your example code, `bindingSource1` will be assigned to the Binding's [Binding.DataSource Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.datasource?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Binding_DataSource) that can receive any `Object`, hence it is a reference to an `Object`. This property is read-only and can not be changed. You can only add or remove a `Binding` to/from a control.  To determine the `DataSource` identity, you would need to do a reference equality comparison.

Comment: How to do a reference equality comparison in this case, could you tell me the example code?

Comment: @TnTinMn  Well, the `[Control].DataBindings[0].PropertyName` will be "Text", `[Control].DataBindings[0].MemberInfo` will be "Address" and `[Control].DataBindings[0].BindingManagerBase.Current` will be the Object (base class) which provides the bindings ("owner" of the bound Property).

Comment: Many thanks, for the comments, this is what I need to do: If textBox1.DataBindings(0).DataSource Is bindingSource1 Then .... End If

Comment: @Bens answer your own question and accept it in orther to mark this question as answered, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys, because of your comments, finally I got the idea how to achive my goal, this is what I need to do:

If textBox1.DataBindings(0).DataSource Is bindingSource1 Then

'do the jobs

End If